# How to type in a <ul> section and click on the first <il> result with Puppeteer and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to access, login a browse a webpage. I am trying to interact with the page and particularly with a search bar, that returns elements based on what the user type in the search bar.
I am trying to type in this section and select the first result that is returned by the search bar.I do manage to type in this section, but I can find a way to select the first result returned.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const urlToConnect = '{url}';
const tennisUrl = 'searchUrl'
const username_param = 'username-login'
const password_param = 'password-login'


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(urlToConnect);

    await page.type(`#${username_param}`, '{username}');
    await page.type(`#${password_param}`, '{password}');

    await page.waitForSelector('button[name="Submit"]');
    await page.click('button[name="Submit"]');

    await sleep(1000);

    await page.goto(tennisUrl)

    let input = await page.waitForSelector("#whereToken > li > input");
    await input.type("Example of Input");

    await sleep(5000);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

[Here is the HTML code of the page and the section i am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AsNy.png)

Then I want to click on the first result appearing:
[Click On Results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKZNl.png)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The only problem I can see in your code without knowing the url to look at its code is that you do not have `await page.waitForSelector(...)`s whenever you are using `goto` or clicking something.